# Why using await is also giving a pending promise in my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, async-await

Why I am getting pending promises even after using `await` in the `getCart()` method? Is there something conceptually wrong in my code?

Please help. Thank you!

```
class User {
  constructor(..., cart) {
      //...
      this.cart = cart; //{items: []}
  }

  getCart() {
    return (async () => {
        const products = this.cart.items.map(async (item) => {
            const product = await Products.getProductDetail(item.productId);    //this returns a promise.
            product.qty = item.qty;
            return product; //<pending> Promise
        });  
        console.log(products);  //<pending> Promise
        return products;  
    })();
  }
}
```

Here is the function call:

```
exports.renderCart = (req, res, next) => {
    (async () => {
        const products = await req.user.getCart(); //req.user is a User class object, ignore it.
        console.log(products);  //pending promise :(
        res.render('shop/cart', { products, pageTitle: 'Cart'});
    })();
};
```

Comment: In `getCart()` you should `await` the value for `products`. Also, it seems like you should use `Promise.all` as it's an array of promises.

Comment: Also, the async IIFE in `getCart` and `renderCart` seems quite unnecessary.

Comment: async functions automatically return a Promise. Return value can be accessed either from `await`ing in another async function of with Promise.then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`products` in your code is an array of promises. You need to wait for them all to finish using `Promise.all`.

The problem can be demonstrated with a bit of a mockup

```js
var fakeWait = x => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(x), 1000));

function test(){
  const items = [1,2,3,4,5]

  const result = items.map( async x => await fakeWait(x));
  console.log(result); // list of unresolved promises
}

async function test2(){
  const items = [1,2,3,4,5]

  const result = await Promise.all(items.map( async x => await fakeWait(x)));
  console.log(result); // list of resolved values
}

test();
test2();
```

In addition, your `getCart` method is overly complex - it does not need to be an IIFE

```
getCart() {        
    const products = this.cart.items.map(async (item) => {
            const product = await Products.getProductDetail(item.productId);    //this returns a promise.
            product.qty = item.qty;
            return product; //<pending> Promise
    });  
    return Promise.all(products);          
}
```

And then simply:

```
const products = await req.user.getCart();
```

Comment: Many thanks @jamiec. Your answer helped me to resolve the issue as well as taught me something more about Promises. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Mitanshu Glad I could help!